# migrate a portion of a mysql table to SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have a mysql table set up like so:

```
user_id | document
44        [blob]
44        [blob]
44        [blob]
46        [blob]
```

I'd like to export all of `user_id` 44's data to an SQLite3 file.

Best way to go about this without writing a script that reads the data and dumps it into a SQLite file?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data via some admin interface (mysqladmin, sequel pro, phpmyadmin) and dump it into sqlite via an sqlite admin interface (phpsqliteadmin)